# (eval):export:1: not valid in this context

Tags: hadoop, ssh, zsh, zshrc

I run "brew install hadoop" without any configuration, after that, I generated a public key by using the following lines :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and then I tried "ssh localhost",something went wrong and I tried that again, it worked, but I got this when I open iIterm2 every time.

```
Last login: Sun Jul 21 16:44:36 on ttys001
You have new mail.
(eval):export:1: not valid in this context: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/amber/opt/phantomjs/bin:/Users/amber/opt/adb:/usr/local/android-sdk-macosx//tools:/usr/local/android-sdk-macosx//platform-tools:/usr/local/android-sdk-macosx//build-tools/27.0.3//Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Applications/VMware
```

Here is part of the zsh script:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/amber/.oh-my-zsh
...
eval export PATH="/Users/amber/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:${PATH}";
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_INIT=1;
_pyenv_virtualenv_hook() {
  local ret=$?
  if [ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then
    eval "$(pyenv sh-activate --quiet || pyenv sh-deactivate --quiet || true)" || true
  else
    eval "$(pyenv sh-activate --quiet || true)" || true
  fi
  return $ret
};
typeset -g -a precmd_functions
if [[ -z $precmd_functions[(r)_pyenv_virtualenv_hook] ]]; then
  precmd_functions=(_pyenv_virtualenv_hook $precmd_functions);
fi
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/nss/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "($(jenv init -))"
```

What exactly is the problem? Does the message matter? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was removing `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public`, look for other files there that may correspond to entries in `(eval):export:1: not valid in this context: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:...`

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult not knowing which `eval` the error comes from.

Regarding the first one before the `export` (config line 4), I don't understand why it is there. It just seems to be a regular prepending to the `$PATH` which normally does not require `eval`.

Regarding the last eval for jenv, the line on their website is different from yours, it says:

```
eval "$(jenv init -)"
```

It is worth changing it just in case.

Also it would not make it invalid but you have in your `$PATH` a few things that you may want to look at. Paths with double slash (most likely a typo) work at least on Zsh but it is better if you make sure there is only slash one just in case.

Also your first one `Fusion.app/Contents/Public` is a relative path. If you want it to work everywhere you would need to put the absolute path instead. Maybe I am being confused and I don't understand the specifics but in this case the applications there are gonna be found only if you are in the directory containing `Fusion.app`. Personally the only relative path I have in `$PATH` is `.` which is a convenient one to have first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I finally figured it out.  I upgraded macOS version which didn't match the virtualBox app's version (Fusion.app) and caused it. What I need to do is remove virtualBox' configuration file and everything is as perfect as before.

Comment: Removing eval from the export resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by removing an duplicate line from .zprofile.

Here's the duplicate extra line that I removed from .zprofile:

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YourComputerUserName/flutter/bin

If you're unable to find & open your .zprofile, you can follow these steps:

1.Start up Terminal

2.Type "cd ~/" to go to your home folder

3. Type "open .zprofile"
4. The window should pop open and you can start editing.

source: [How to find .zprofile and what the .zprofile file should look like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHsaky_SkjY)

The terminal should automatically open the text file. There you can edit and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

When I installed the jenv, This error occurs, It works for me to delete the eval before the export in the .zshrc file.